# Laravel : how to search multiple value from database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

On my search having `$categroy_id - $country_id - $city_id`. there is a table `activities` with all that value.

I just implement a function in my controller but its return all data.

My controller function code:

```
public function PlanActivity(Request $request){
    $category_id = $request->category_id;
    $countryid = $request->country_id;
    $cityid = $request->city_id;
    $listactivity = Activity::all(); // get all activity
    if($category_id != '') {
        $listactivity->where('category_id', function ($query) use ($category_id) {
            $query->where('category_id', $category_id);
        });
    }

    return view('front.plan_activity',compact('listactivity'));
}
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use multiple where clauses:

Query Builder

```
// match any one of the values
$activities = DB::table('activities')->where('category_id', $category_id)
                       ->orWhere('country_id', $country_id)
                       ->orWhere('city_id', $city_id)
                       ->get();

// match all of the values
$activities = DB::table('activities')->where('category_id', $category_id)
                       ->where('country_id', $country_id)
                       ->where('city_id', $city_id)
                       ->get();
```

Eloquent

```
// match any one of the values
$activities = Activity::where('category_id', $category_id)
                       ->orWhere('country_id', $country_id)
                       ->orWhere('city_id', $city_id)
                       ->get();

// match all of the values
$activities = Activity::where('category_id', $category_id)
                       ->where('country_id', $country_id)
                       ->where('city_id', $city_id)
                       ->get();

// this can be merged together in one array
$activities = Activity::where([
     'category_id' => $category_id,
     'country_id' => $country_id,
     'city_id' => $city_id
])->get();
```

If the request parameters are null

```
public function PlanActivity(Request $request){
    if (!$categroy_id && !$country_id && !$city_id) {
        $activities = Activity::all();
    } else {
        // do the above queries
    }

    return view('front.plan_activity',compact('activities'));
}
```

Comment: i want to set this query on model ? how can i do this?

Comment: one more thng that if do not have `$categroy_id - $country_id - $city_id` is null return all activity..how can i set.

Comment: First you need to create a model for your activity table.                       
class Activity extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'activities'; //table name
    protected $guarded = [];
}
 Then you can write queries like he said above                            
    $activities = Activity::where('category_id', $category_id)
                       ->orWhere('country_id', $country_id)
                       ->orWhere('city_id', $city_id)
                       ->get();

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in the use of the eloquent functions that Laravel's models provide. When you call the `all()` function, it basically does a `SELECT * FROM` your table and returns the results as an object. If you need to filter this query or add anything, you will no longer use `all()`, but instead use `get()` as the last function.

As for setting this query on the model, you are already inside the model! When you call `Activity::whatever-function-next()` you are inside the model, and Laravel already gives you all these functions to create you query with little effort. The first answer gave you all you need, just be sure to understand what those functions and classes are actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this query to perform search,**

```
public function PlanActivity(Request $request)
{
    $category_id = $request->category_id;
    $country_id = $request->country_id;
    $city_id = $request->city_id;
    $activity = new Activity; // get all activity
    $search = $activity->search();
    if($category_id) {
       $search->where('category_id', $category_id);
    }
    if($country_id){
       $search->where('country_id', $country_id);
    }
    if($city_id){
      $search->where('city_id', $city_id);
    }


    $listactivity = $search->

    return view('front.plan_activity',compact('listactivity'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a model for your activity table.

```
class Activity extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'activities'; //table name
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

Then you can write queries like he said above

```
$activities = Activity::where('category_id', $category_id)
                           ->orWhere('country_id', $country_id)
                           ->orWhere('city_id', $city_id)
                           ->get();
```